# Error using haarcascade_profileface.xml

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

I am writing a program in C# using Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows Desktop. I want to detect faces that are in profile, so just one eye is visible. I am using haarcascade_profileface.xml for the detection. Every time I try to debug my code I receive this error message:

> *Error of type "Emgu.CV.Util.CvException" has occurred in Emgu.CV.dll. Additional Information: OpenCV: The node does not represent a user
>   object (unknown type?)*

I use the same code that I use with haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml and with this xml it works.

I really need help. Please help me.
Thanks, B

Answer (score 2):

emgu, using opencv's deprecated c-api, can only read cascade files in the old format (build with opencv_haartraining). you cannot use that cascade file with emgu. blame their devs for living under a rock.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Is it possible to get it running by using the new function haarcascade.detect? if yes, do you have any experience with this function and are able to tell me how to use it?

Answer (score 2):

Use the haarcascade files from here instead: https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/tree/master/data/haarcascades_cuda

As berak said, yours are in the wrong format

Comment: Appreciate the insight. My algorithim only references a single frontal face cascade file. How do you reference multiple inside a using statement? Or would I be better off by putting all the git files into a single xml page?

Comment: Sorry it's been a few years since I've worked with this, your best bet would be to submit a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Emgu using libs from OpenCV, so you need add this libs into your project. The visual studio can´t add as reference the native OpneCV libs, so you can include the libs on root project and set to build always copy to folder 'bin'.

[image]

Set project to buld for 64bit processor